# How do I get tags to show up in individual Tumblr posts and not on my Tumblr theme page?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Is there a way to change the [Quite Big](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/9601) theme so that my tags show up only on individual posts, but not on the overview when you scroll through all the posts on my blog's homepage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want your tags code added into a Permalink block - which means the Permalink page is where they will show. Same for anything you don't want to see on the Index or main page. This, however, depends on how the rest of the theme is written, and often one has to experiement with Blocks.